# moderncv / cventry - Insert empty lines in first argument while keeping all content right aligned

Tags: moderncv

What I would like to do is insert an empty line after "full time" and "part time". This empty line should be limited to the first argument of `\cventry`. So that the horizontal expansion of the empty line is limited to the first column. However, when I issue two `\newline` after "full time", "full time" is no longer right aligned. A bonus would be, if there would be a vertical alignment between the first argument of `\cventry` and the following arguments. In other words, if the lines would be on the same level.

A MWE is given below. The compiling errors are thrown because of some missing entries like phone number but do not influence the appearance of `\cventry`.

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue} 
\usepackage{array}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Experience}

\cventry{%
99/9999 \mbox{-- 99/9999} \mbox{full time}
% \newline \newline
99/9999  \mbox{-- 99/9999} \mbox{part time}
99/9999  \mbox{-- 99/9999} \mbox{part time}%
}{Job title}{Company}{}{}{%
\begin{itemize}%
\item Item 1
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Item 11
        \item Item 12
        \item Item 13
    \end{itemize}
\item Item 2
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Item 21
        \item Item 22
        \item Item 23
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
}

\end{document}
```

The result should look like this. Although, I left out the part with the alignment in the picture since it is very cumbersome to do it with a drawing program.

[image]

Result with two `\newline`

[image]

I tried to fumble around with `\hfill`, `\hspace` and alignment commands like `\ragged...` but could not achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by inserting pseudo empty lines using `\hphantom`. In contrast to the case when issuing `newline`, the phrases 'full time' and 'part time' stay right aligned as intended. It might not be the most elegant solution but it works.

MWE

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue} 
\usepackage{array}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Experience}

\cventry{%
99/9999 \mbox{-- 99/9999} \mbox{full time}
{\leavevmode\hphantom{dummy}}
99/9999  \mbox{-- 99/9999} \mbox{part time}
{\leavevmode\hphantom{dummy}}
99/9999  \mbox{-- 99/9999} \mbox{part time}%
}{Job title}{Company}{}{}{%
\begin{itemize}%
\item Item 1
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Item 11
        \item Item 12
        \item Item 13
    \end{itemize}
\item Item 2
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Item 21
        \item Item 22
        \item Item 23
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]